# Best Way To Determine If SQL Query Has Named Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have done a bunch of searching via both Google and Stack Overflow and, if there are answers out there, I haven't been able to come up with a search query that gives me the answer for which I am looking.

I am building a module of functions to use in my ASP.net website to handle all of the dirty work of connecting to Microsoft SQL Server DB's and performing queries. I am currently working on the functions that perform the queries and have decided to allow for an optional function parameter that is an array of SQL parameters.

In the functions that have optional SQL parameters passed to them, I would like to check the SQL query passed to see if there is a named parameter. If there is a named parameter in the SQL query, make sure the optional SQL parameters were indeed passed. If there are no named parameters in the SQL query, then make sure that no SQL parameters were passed. For example:

- SQL query = `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @TheID` → function call must have SQL parameters.
- SQL query = `SELECT GETDATE()` → function call must NOT have SQL parameters.

***My question to everyone out there is*** what is the best way to "search" the string that is the SQL query for a named parameter (without knowing the name of the parameter). I am wary of just searching the string for the '@' character because I read somewhere that it is possible to have a column named with that character (e.g. `[name@domain]`). Perhaps I can use a regular expression to search for '=' followed by any number of whitespace followed by '@'?

Comment: I would use "LIKE ' * @ * ' or LIKE '%@%', depending on your wildcard operator (The SQL server wildcard operator slips my mind at the moment) EDIT: for asp.net use the instr() function

Comment: `@@` is used as a prefix for some built in system functions.

Comment: Thanks, Damien, for the reminder of that. Even though that is HIGHLY unlikely to happen in the code that I would write, it is still nice to check for all possibilities for completeness and solid code!

Answer (score 0):

No reason why you can't use the `@` character. There shouldn't be an `@` in the name since its a variable and not a column. You can't have a variable named `@(var@iable)`

Check out [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). It's a good example that does something very similar to what you're trying to do

Comment: I wasn't saying that there might be an `@` in the parameter name (variable name). I was saying that there might be a column name with an `@` character in it, or like @aaron-bertrand hinted at, an inline comment in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

For .net,

```
  function checkQuery (byVal myQuery As String)

    return not instr(myQuery,"@") == 0
end function
```

Would return true if your query contains "@"

Comment: What if my query is `SELECT /* @foo */ * FROM dbo.table;` or `SELECT [foo@bar] FROM dbo.[my@table];`? Comments and poorly-named entities can lead to false positives.

Comment: Yes, they would. This was just as simple of an example as I could provide. If you are looking for very specific matches, then you would need to write a regular expression. As far as I know, that would be the only solution.